constrain type parameter to pointers: cannot use type T outside of a type constraint
I have been trying to implement a matrix package in Go.
Consider this:
package matrix

type Numeric interface {
    ~int | ~float64 | ~complex128 | ~uint
}

type Matrix interface {
    ~[][]int | ~[][]uint | ~[][]float64 | ~[][]complex128
}

This means any function that returns a [][](Numeric type) would implement the matrix interface. This seems pretty straightforward but that doesn't work.
Say:
func Transpose[m *Matrix](mat m){
    //i should be able to perform a type switch here
    //to determine the type of "matrix" i received but i cant
    //some code
}

The IDE immediately notifies me that:

"cannot use type Matrix outside of a type constraint: interface contains type constraints"

I have tried everything I could get my hands on like using reflect.Typeof() or passing the type as a var like mattype := (*mat).(type)

func Transpose[m *Matrix](mat m){ should be func Transpose[m Matrix](mat *m){

Your syntax is invalid. You are using Matrix as if it were a regular interface type by adding the star * operator in front of it; *Matrix means "pointer to Matrix". However you used it in place of a type parameter constraint, within a type parameter list (the part in square brackets).
Type constraints don't need pointers. If you want to restrict the function to accept only "pointers to things that implement Matrix" put * before the function argument:
func Transpose[M Matrix](mat *M) {
}

However this is still not useful. You defined Matrix as a union of different slice types, hence you can't do anything with it such as range, due to this issue: How to iterate over a union of slices passed in a generic function? (T has no core type)
Instead, parametrize Matrix itself:
type Matrix[N Numeric] interface {
    ~[][]N
}

func Transpose[N Numeric, M Matrix[N]](mat *M) {
    // your code
}

